# jquery mobile 'live' function undefined in phonegap application

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to get this [example](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt1part1) working with phonegap 2.7 and jquery mobile 1.3.1. 
I started with the following index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />

        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();           
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page-home">
            <div data-role="header" data-nobackbtn="true" data-theme="e">
                <h1>Hello world app</h1>
            </div> <!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content" id="content-manual" data-theme="a">

            <div data-role="button" id="playaudio" data-theme="e">Play</div>
            <div data-role="button" id="pauseaudio" data-theme="e">Pause</div>
            <div data-role="button" id="stopaudio" data-theme="e">Stop</div>    

            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a"> Current: <span id="audio_position">0 sec</span></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">Total: <span id=media_dur>0</span> sec</div>
            </div><!-- /grid-a -->

    </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

And the following index.js file:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        $('#page-home').live('pageinit',function(){
            console.log("Hello world!");
            $("#playaudio").live('tap', function() {
                // Note: two ways to access media file: web and local file        
                var src = 'http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3';

                // local (on device): copy file to project's /assets folder:
                // var src = '/android_asset/spittinggames.m4a';

                playAudio(src);
            });

            $("#pauseaudio").live('tap', function() {
                pauseAudio();
            });

            $("#stopaudio").live('tap', function() {
                stopAudio();
            });
        });

    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
//        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
//        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
//        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
//
//        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
//        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
//
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

For some reason, when the application starts, I see an error from the web console that says:

```
TypeError: Result of expression '$('#page-home').live' [undefined] is not a function. at file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:44
```

For the record, I know that jquery mobile is loaded successfully, but for some reason, the `live` function isn't recognized.
Anyone knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method don't exist any more in jQuery 1.9 + it was deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and it should be replace with method **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**.

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().
>
> This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the
>   document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers
>   when content is dynamically added to a page. See the discussion of
>   direct versus delegated events in the .on() method for more
>   information.
>
> Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its successors is
>   straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all
>   three event attachment methods....

Change:

```
$("#pauseaudio").live('tap', function() {
    pauseAudio();
});
```

to this:

```
$("#pauseaudio").on('tap', function() {
    pauseAudio();
});
```

or this if you want to delegate event:

```
$(document).on('tap','#pauseaudio' , function() {
    pauseAudio();
});
```